# PWA install Icon not appearing on Windows but Android is fine

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, icons, progressive-web-apps

On Windows, I defer the Install prompt for my [Brotkrumen](https://richardmaher.github.io/Brotkrumen/TravelManager.html) PWA but when I invoke event.prompt() later, I see a black square with the letter "B" in it and not my Ginger Bread House icon. This also happens if I click the Chrome/Edge/Opera/Firefox native install buttons directly.

If I say yes to install, then I also only get the white B on black background on homescree or Apps folder.

On my Android phone, everything works with the gingerbreadhouse.png icon appearing in both the install-confirm prompt and in the App folder. Edge/Firefox/Opera browsers are "branded" or badged on top of icon. Chrome and Samsung are not.

I've cleared all Caches and seen that my debug/applicatio/manifest has the images displayed and my Fetch API handler serves up the image when the confirm prompt appears but no house is forthcoming.

The code is not minimized but all source can be found [in GitHub](https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen)

Thanks.

PS. Slight nit: - Chrome webkit says "Added to home screen" when it isn't. It's Added to the Apps folder.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that on windows the icon image has to be either a square or 192x192 pixels.

I hadn't bother to resize the icon or change its aspect ratio as it alsways worked on the phone.

I tried the [A2HS](https://mdn.github.io/pwa-examples/a2hs/) and just copied that icon's dimensions.